# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '='

Tags: php, mysql

I'm just starting out in programming i'm hitting my head at the moment against the wall cos i don't understand what is wrong with the following code

```
    mysql_query=("UPDATE tech_kunena_messages 
    SET tech_kunena_messages.parent=tech_kunena_topics.first_post_id 
    FROM tech_kunena_messages INNER JOIN  tech_kunena_topics 
    ON tech_kunena_messages.thread = tech_kunena_topics.id");
```

I'm getting a Parse error: `syntax error, unexpected '='` i'm trying to update the `_kunena_messages.parent` with the `first_post_id` from `kunena_topics` as long as the `.thread` and `.id` are the same... I don't understand why i've got an unexpected =.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Change `mysql_query=("UPDATE ...` to `$query = mysql_query("UPDATE ...`

Comment: You shouldn't use mysql_ anymore but mysqli_. mysql_ is deprecated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [the manual](http://nl1.php.net/mysql_query).

Answer (score 4):

```
mysql_query=(" ... )
```

should be

```
mysql_query("
```

Edit: you should be using mysqli_*( ... ) as mysql_*() is deprecated.

Comment: You might want to have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php for more info as to why you should use MySQLi and some helpful code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, remove `=` after `mysql_query`

```
mysql_query("UPDATE tech_kunena_messages 
    SET tech_kunena_messages.parent=tech_kunena_topics.first_post_id 
    FROM tech_kunena_messages INNER JOIN  tech_kunena_topics 
    ON tech_kunena_messages.thread = tech_kunena_topics.id");
```

Comment: haha oh the times of a newbie.. so simple, Thanks very much for your time

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for a join in an `update` in MySQL is:

```
UPDATE tech_kunena_messages INNER JOIN
       tech_kunena_topics 
       ON tech_kunena_messages.thread = tech_kunena_topics.id
  SET tech_kunena_messages.parent = tech_kunena_topics.first_post_id ;
```

There is no `FROM` clauses used with `UPDATE` (in MySQL).

I am intentionally ignoring the non-SQL related issues, such as using "mysql_" instead of "mysqli_" or PDO.